# Alternative to windows console app c#

Tags: c#, console

Basically, I am creating a text based RPG, however would like to release it once it is done, Is there any alternatives to console app that looks a bit nicer when released for publicity.

Also, what would be the best framework to use if i where to publish a project like this to android orr apple market?

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/440269/whats-a-good-alternative-windows-console?rq=1 was closed, ergo this one should be too.

Comment: Why would you use a console application for this? Why don't you use a web application?

Answer (score 5):

You could create a WindowsForms application or even a WPF application where you place a huge TextBox on the form. Set the background-color to black and the fore-color to something you like. This way you "simulate" a console, but you have the advantage of using a forms application. Now you can add little extras to the UI to make it look nicer that just a console.

Answer (score -1):

If you really want to improve design you should consider using WPF. It's from Microsoft too, and you can download Visual Studio Express for WPF.

Actually the VS Express for WPF can be downloaded at:
http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/products/visual-studio-express-for-windows-desktop

Good luck :)